# How Insert Native Ads on Newsfeed Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, native, ads

I want to insert native ads on my wordpress newsfeed. The native ads just have title, short description. Then the link pointed to landing page website which have by advertiser.

Where i can insert the code for that purpose ?